# How to add clickable background image under logo

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add  a clickable background image under a my logo to link to external page. The problems are the way I add code breaks the Bootstraps Menu Collapse option and logo does not become responsive as expected. my site link is "sirtcantalilar.com" you can check it. My fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/NJTH4/1/ . When I resize page logo starts to go down below in the page. 
Here is the way I add my logo and bg image:

Header:

```
     <!--HEADER-->
       <header>
          <div class="container">
           <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/images/sirtcantalilar-logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
  </header>
     <!--CONTAINER--> /*BREAKS THIS MENU COLLAPSE
        <div class="container">
            <!--MENU-->
            <nav class="clearfix">
                <a href="" id="menu-button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>  
                <ul class="menu col-md-9 list-inline">
                    <li><a href="/">Anasayfa</a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
```

css rules :

```
header .container{
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 195px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    left:0px;
    top:25px;
}
```

What is the best way to add a clickable background image under a logo?
Thanks

edit 1:
if anyone is interested here is the right code that works as I want.

```
<header>
    <div class="container topperpart">
        <a href="/" title="Sirtcantalilar">
            <img src="http://cdn.sirtcantalilar.com/assets/img/sirtcantalilar-logo.png" class="toplogo img-responsive" alt="sirtcantalilar-logo" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/wingoya-katil" target="_blank" title="Wingoya Katıl">
            <img src="http://cdn.sirtcantalilar.com/assets/img/banner-yeni.jpeg" class="topbanner" alt="wingo-katil" /></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
img.topbanner
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #3b6d80;
}

img.toplogo {
    z-index: 2;
    position:absolute;
    padding:3px 0px 0px 25px;
   max-width: 40%;  
}
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle demo pls

Comment: I added my site link. is it enough I could not use jsfiddle. I tried now

Comment: if someone got a similar question and your site changed its annoying

Comment: Aaroniker , added the right code and link of my site. I am trying to be carefull on SO but I was very tired of trying that sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more clear with the question.

Did you try giving z-index to logo?

Also, I notice the div inside header and also for the nav has same name - container.

Can you try giving a different name and check?

Comment: added fiddle . sorry first time I use fiddle link.

Comment: This is a template from Themeforest. The menu shall lay after logo and banner. If I take them under same container. The Menu is stocked over the banner image.

Comment: @ytsejam - did you try whatever I mentioned above?

Comment: yes. Solved by z-index and position relative , absolute. but logo is not like the way I want. http://sirtcantalilar.com .. can you resize the window to see the problem. I am updating my jsfiddle in the question.

Comment: @ytsejam To resize images & page elements upon window resize you'll need Responsive Web Designing (RWD) Concepts. Right now you are able to notice the background image (wingo) only getting resized because it has width:100%. So when width is set to percentage values, they get resized. But we can't keep giving percentage values to everything like you want for logo. Hence you have to get into RWD. RWD allows you to resize a lot of html elements on the page according to any size of the window. To learn that it will take a lot of time. Until you learn it leave it as it is.

Comment: I added  to my img.toplogo max-width = 40% and it works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: @ytsejam yes. Like I said, you can play around by giving percentage values - it will have some effect. However, on the longer run and the right holistic approach would be to stick to RWD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the background image a CSS background image on the `<header>`.
2. Float the first link left and the second link right
3. **Only have the turkish airline link clickable around the advertisement image** ... otherwise it is way too easy to click that link by accident when the user actually wants your homepage. That would make me as a user, very frustrated.

In this example the pink block is the first link to your homepage. Click anywhere within that pink area and you will be taken there. The blue block is the link to the Turkish Airlines site. Obviously the colours are there just to show you how the links are positioned :)

**Updated** - Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/d3j93/1/)

HTML

```
<header>
    <a href="/" title="Sirtcantalilar" class="logoLink">
    <img src="http://cdn.sirtcantalilar.com/assets/img/sirtcantalilar-logo.png" class="toplogo" alt="sirtcantalilar-logo" />
    </a>

    <a id="otherLink" href="http://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/wingoya-katil" target="_blank" title="Wingoya Katıl">

    </a>

</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    width: 1190px;
    height: 195px;
    background: url("http://cdn.sirtcantalilar.com/assets/img/banner-yeni.jpeg") no-repeat;
}
img.toplogo {
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
a.logoLink {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 600px;
    height: 195px;
}
#otherLink {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 530px;
    height: 195px;
}
```

Comment: added fiddle . sorry first time I use fiddle link.

Comment: Please have a look at my revised answer and jsfiddle :)

Comment: I added my fiddle. can you check this link "sirtcantalilar.com" when I resize window, logo is not getting smaller. If I solve it, it will be perfect.

Comment: Thanks misterManSam. I wanted all the background image lay down under logo. I dont know what ruins menu but rewritten all and menu collapse button works now.